# How to calculate avg of some column in join?

Tags: sql-server

i have three tables

## teacher

```
id name 
1  ali
2  reza
```

## course

```
id title
1  math
2  litrature
```

## gradetbl

```
id courseid teacherid grade 
1  1        1         20
2  2        1         10
3  1        2         17
```

## the result:

```
teacherid avg(grade)
1         15
2         17
```

i try something but it did not work

Comment: You should actually add what it is you tried to your question so that someone can let you know where you are going wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you really need to do is to `SELECT` from the `gradetbl`, apply the `AVG` aggregate function over the `grade` and then `GROUP BY` the `teacherid` like so:

```
SELECT teacherid, AVG(grade)
  FROM gradetbl
 GROUP BY teacherid;
```

For the results you have indicated there should be no need to use a `JOIN` at all. You will only need to use a `JOIN` when you want to fetch data associated with the `teacherid`:

```
SELECT t.name, AVG(g.grade)
  FROM gradetbl AS g
  JOIN teacher as t
    ON t.id = g.teacherid
 GROUP BY t.name;
```

You should view the documentation for [SELECT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql), [GROUP BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql) and [AVG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/avg-transact-sql) for thorough examples and explanations of common usage.